# Logstash filter with custom geopoint

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, geolocation, logstash

i'm trying the following:

I have a custom Logstash filter and within this filter i have latitude and longitude values. I now want to create a new field (Serv_location) that uses the lat and lon values, so i can create a world-map with these geopoints in kibana. My Problem is that when i create the new field, it interprets it as a digit/number field in logstash and not as a therefore needed geopoint field.

currently my code looks like this to add the field:

```
 event['serv_location'] = [geo_lat.to_f, geo_lng.to_f]
```

what else do i need to do, to create a geopoint field?

Edit:

Here is the mapping i did:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:5601/logstash-2015.04.16/_mapping/location' -d '
  {
              "map_location" : 
              {
                   "properties" : {
                   "location" : {"type" : "geo_point", "store" : true }
                   }
               }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a custom mapping? If yes, how does your mapping for the new `serv_location` field look like?

Comment: I updated my post, see above

Comment: Yes, you just need to rename your field to `serv_location` (instead of `location`) and the URL as `/_mapping/map_location` instead. Please try again.

Comment: ok when i try to do it i get the following error: {"error":"RemoteTransportException[[server][inet[/<ip>]][indices:admin/mapping/put]]; nested: IndexMissingException[[logstash-2015.04.16] missing]; ","status":404}

Comment: It means you don't have any index called `logstash-2015.04.16`, you should use an existing index

Comment: Nice, happy to help!

Comment: so one more thing: the mapping was created successfully but now i have a mapping conflict and it does not show the world map symbol next to location, its an exclamation mark!

Answer (score 0):

Please write custom mapping for this field and define "type" : "geo_point". Hopefully, this will solve your problem

Comment: so one more thing: the mapping was created successfully but now i have a mapping conflict and it does not show the world map symbol next to location, its an exclamation mark!